# Parallel process in Apache Camel

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, apache-camel

I have an apache camel route defined like this:

```
from("timer:name?period=3000&fixedRate=true")
            .process(myDbProcessor);
```

`myDbProcessor` implements Processor interface. It simply gets some data from DB and executes HTTP Post request.

All good, but sometimes we have huge data in DB and we have to start a new instance of the application to improve our performance.

So I need to make `myDbProcessor` parallel working in different threads. I need advice on what is the best and simplest way to use multithreading and parallel processing `myDbProcessor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html) for example, with `parallelProcessing=true` and a custom `onPrepareRef` to split the workload. Multicast to the same target route.

Anyway, you should refactor your code first. Camel is not meant to be used with [God Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), but with [pipelines](https://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html). Each step of your processing (eg: start, fetch data, do HTTP Post, process the result, loop to next record) should be implemented in its own Processor or route.
You can achieve a better modularity and leverage all [EIP patterns](https://camel.apache.org/eip.html).